# Found nil while unwrapping an optional value - Swift 2

Tags: swift2, option-type

I am getting this error which I cannot explain:

```
@IBOutlet weak var licencePlateLabel: UILabel!

var editItem: CarValues? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view.
            self.configureView()
        }
    }

 func configureView() {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.

        if let editedCar = self.editItem {

            if let licencePlate = self.licencePlateLabel {
                licencePlate.text? = editedCar.licencePlate!//this gives me nil
            }
            else {
                print("value was nil")
                }

           print(editedCar.licencePlate!)//this is giving me the correct value

}
```

if I replace the

```
if let licencePlate = self.licencePlateLabel {
                    licencePlate.text! = editedCar.licencePlate!
                }//this throws an error "found nil......"
```

even if I do this I m still getting the "found nil..."

```
 func configureView() {

 licencePlateLabel.text = "test"
       [...]
}
```

BUT if I put the above on viewDidLoad then it works fine

```
override func viewDidLoad() {  

 licencePlateLabel.text = "test"
           [...]

}
```

What is going on in this code?

**EDIT**

I am passing the value of the editItem from the detailView to the EditView like this:

```
  @IBAction func editButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let editScreen = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ID_EditViewController")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(editScreen, animated: true)

        let controller =  EditViewController()
        controller.editItem = detailItem
        controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
        controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't unwrap properties to *set* them, only to read from them.  So your code can simply be:

```
if let licencePlate = self.licencePlateLabel {
    licencePlate.text = editedCar.licencePlate
}
```

Note that because `licencePlate.text` is an optional value anyway, there is also no need to unwrap `editedCar.licencePlate`. It's ok to use its value whether it is nil or contains a String.

Comment: I m still getting nil if I do that

Comment: @GeorgeAsda Are you sure that the `editedCar` has a licencePlate value at this point?  You can try changing your if-let to be:  `if let editedCar = self.editItem, where editedCar.licencePlate != nil` and set a breakpoint to see if that condition is met.

Comment: Shouldn't the  print(editedCar.licencePlate!) which is called BEFORE the if let[...] give nil as well?

Comment: I ran the if let editedCar = self.editItem where editedCar.licencePlate != nil { and i do get the value in my print log but the value I get on the label text is nil

Comment: @GeorgeAsda  It sounds like your `configureView` might be running before your label IBOutlet is hooked up. You print the value from `editedCar` regardless of whether the label exists yet or was set. So yes, it prints, but the label may be connected afterwards and never then have its text set. Make sure that before any other code sets the `editItem` property that it calls `loadViewIfNeeded()` on your view controller first, to force all the outlets to be connected before your `configureView()` code runs

Comment: I am using Apple's standard code to pass info between controllers (master detail) I don't really get why the textfield is set after i call my configureView(). I am also calling it at viewDidLoad but the second time it just doesn't do anything as the object is nil